# How to check how many bytes a compressed string consist of?

Tags: python-3.x, string, compression

I Have compressed two strings with **zlib** using **python 3** like this:

```
t1 = "Hi my name is David"
t2 = t1* 10
t1Compressed = zlib.compress(t1.encode())
t10Compressed = zlib.compress(t10.encode())
```

Now I want to count how many bytes **t1Compressed** and **t10Compressed** consists of. How can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type is `bytes` so just use the `len()` method

```
>>> t1 = "Hi my name is David"
>>> t2 = t1* 10
>>> t1Compressed = zlib.compress(t1.encode())
>>> t10Compressed = zlib.compress(t2.encode())
>>> type(t1Compressed)
<class 'bytes'>
>>> len(t1Compressed)
27
>>> len(t10Compressed)
30
```

Comment: How did you get 27 and 30  on, I get 64 and 74 ??

Comment: I'm on python3.8 but not sure I'll I did was run the code above. I can reproduce the above answer reliably

Answer (score 1):

`len(t1Compressed)` gives the length of the bytes.

If in doubt when you want to find the length of something in Python, try `len`.